# How to remove fractions of seconds from a Date variable?

Tags: ms-access, vba, odbc

#### Background:

I read the [`pwdLastSet`](http://www.selfadsi.org/ads-attributes/user-pwdLastSet.htm) attribute from Active Directory, and want to store it in a `DATETIME2(0)` column in a SQL Server table. I don't want to store fractions of seconds.

It's an 8-byte Integer, expressed in 100-nanosecond steps since 12:00 AM, January 1, 1601. I use [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53631932/3820271) to convert it to a Date variable.

This continued to fail with `ODBC-call failed`, and it took me quite some time to figure out that the extra precision returned by that function caused the error.

#### Question:

What is the best way to remove fractions of seconds from a `Date` variable?

---

#### How to reproduce:

I use SQL Server 2008 R2 and Access 2010.
In SQL Server:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TestDT (
    ID      INT             NOT NULL,
    colDT2  DATETIME2(0)    NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_TestDT PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
GO
INSERT TestDT (ID) VALUES (1)
GO
```

Link that table into Access, using Native Client ODBC driver or the current [Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/windows/microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server-on-windows?view=sql-server-2017). The default "SQL Server" driver doesn't really know how to work with DATETIME2.

In Access VBA:

```
Public Sub TestDT()

    Dim DB As DAO.Database
    Dim RS As DAO.Recordset
    Dim dte As Date
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set DB = CurrentDb
    
    ' Random date+time
    dte = CDate("2018-12-24 15:16:17")
    
    ' 1st iteration: write original date+time -> works
    ' 2nd iteration: try to write date+time with fractional seconds -> error for DATETIME2(0) column
    
    For i = 1 To 2
        If i = 2 Then
            ' Introduce milliseconds nastiness
            dte = dte + 0.00001
        End If
        Debug.Print "Iteration " & i, Format(dte, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss")
            
        Set RS = DB.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM TestDT WHERE ID = 1", dbOpenDynaset)
    
        With RS
            .Edit
            !colDT2 = dte
            On Error Resume Next
            .Update
            
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                Debug.Print "Error " & Err.Number, Err.Description
                ' The DAO Errors collection shows the actual error
                Debug.Print Errors(0).Description
            Else
                Debug.Print "Update OK"
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0
            
            .Close
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

Output:

```
Iteration 1   2018-12-24 15:16:17
Update OK
Iteration 2   2018-12-24 15:16:18
Error 3146    ODBC-Aufruf fehlgeschlagen.
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Datetime field overflow. 
    Fractional second precision exceeds the scale specified in the parameter binding.
```

Comment: I wonder if you have tried `!colDT2 = format(dte, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")`

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I didn't, will try tomorrow. @krishKM

Comment: Yes, that works too (though it's `"hh:nn:ss"`). Thanks!

Comment: if `mm` is used after `hh`, it does what `nn` does :)

Comment: Whoa, more date/time craziness. You're right. :o @krishKM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could round off to the second this way:

```
PwdLastSetSecond = CDate(Int(PwdLastSet * 86400) / 86400)
```

Comment: The magic number `86400` deserves an explanatory comment IMO, or even better, a named constant, e.g. `Const SecondsPerDay = 86400`

Comment: That's definitely less clumsy! :)

Answer (score 1):

I came up with

```
dte = CDate(Int(dte) + TimeSerial(Hour(dte), Minute(dte), Second(dte)))
```

but that's rather clumsy. :(

Answer (score 1):

The correct function in Access to strip out the time part is:

DateValue(“date/time” expression)

So you thus get:

dte = DateValue (CDate("2018-12-24 15:16:17") )

or DateValue (whatever date time expression)

The correct function in Access to strip out the time part is:

TimeValue(“date/time” expression)

So you thus get:

dte = TimeValue (CDate("2018-12-24 15:16:17") )

or TimeValue (whatever date/ time expression)

If you need to save or strip out the time part into a separate value, then go:

dtMyTime = TimeValue ( (CDate("2018-12-24 15:16:17") )

However YOUR ISSUE is NOT stripping out Date, or time.

There is NO SUCH thing as “.ms” for the format.

That going to give you month + seconds.

If you look close:

2018-12-24 15:16:17.1217

In above, te 1217 is 12th month, and 17 seconds..

**There is NO SUCH thing as “ms” for the format. So this is why you are seeing a overflow**.

So you CAN NOT USE “.ms”.

You can only get the seconds in Access.

Just use a standard format command. If you want to strip out the "extra" time:

```
  Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("dbo_TimeTest2", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

  rst.Edit
  rst!StartTimeD = Format(rst!StartTimeD, "MM-DD-YYYY hh:nn:ss")
  rst.Update
```

DANGER DANGER will Robinson. Access does not use or support “ms” in the format.

Simply using above “format” on the existing date/time you get will pull out and toss out the extra values after the seconds.

Comment: You're completely right about `.ms` being nonsense, I read that [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/198144-vba-how-format-fractions-seconds.html#post967467) but didn't check or even read that thread to the end... That's not the reason for the overflow though. -- Assigning the `Format(.., "MM-DD-YYYY hh:nn:ss")` expression works to remove the fractions.

Comment: But @Andre, note that it will round a subsecond part by 4/5 - to the nearest integer second. It will not round the fraction of seconds off. Neither method is wrong; which to choose depends on the context.

Comment: This had me fooled for sure. I had never seen ".ms" in the format - but the tip off was "month" and "seconds" appearing consistent. All is well since the format does strip out the extra decimal information held by the sql datetime2 formats. They should not creep into the picture, but if the data is not original coming from Access, then that info cannot be used by Access. If stripping out (ignoring) that information is fine, then no problem. If that extra information is needed then this is a challenge and problem.